# Positioning and Coordinates in Tikz+Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

How exactly does positioning in beamer+tikz work?

1. where is the absolute origin (0,0) on a slide? Why when I specify (0,0) does it seem to move around the slide depending on the size of whats being plotted? Does it exist absolutely somewhere?
2. Can I draw **the** absolute grid (as opposed to some grid) with absolute positioning information on slides to help me when trying to position items?
3. Can someone help me make sense of the example below?

Im reading and rereading the tikz (especially chapter 13) and beamer documentation, but cant seem to figure out what is going on.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections,through,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,bbm,bm}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption,float,enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Slide}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (0.5\textwidth,0.5\textheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I remove the `0.5`, why is the grid off the slide in all dimensions?

*Note*: There is this related [unanswered question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400518/coordinates-in-tikz). This question is **not** specifically about this MWE, just in general how to look at a slide, pick a point with my eye, and put something there exactly and absolutely in tikz.

Comment: Use `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]` for the pictures. You can fix the origin of your `tikzpictures` with something like: `\node[xshift=<x>,yshift=<y>] at (current page.south west)` with `<x>` and `<y>` the real position of the node measured from the bottom left corner of the frame.

Comment: My previous comment was stupid, I forgot `remember picture`. So the correct way (IMHO) is `\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] 
        \draw[help lines] (current page.south west) grid 
  (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @marmot I was just about to write a comment :)

Comment: @Skillmon Always remember `remember picture` ;-) Any chance you want to answer the question?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have to say, I'm more curious as to some explanation of how positioning works, why my example doesnt, and why these suggestions will work. I can't make heads or tails of it right now. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: In your example, in the settings you use, beamer wants to center the picture vertically and just puts it with some standard indent. If you were to add stuff, that would move the picture around. If you increase width and/or height, the picture will eventually overshoot. Therefore, you will be better off if you follow @Skillmon's advice and use `overlay,remember picture`.

Comment: ok Ill try that - but in general, how does absolute vs relative positioning work with beamer+tikz? Is there a system where if I put in a coordinate where I want a box to appear, it will appear there come hell or high-water?

Comment: @user79950 if you wait a few more minutes I'll probably write an answer for you.

Comment: I think you can find some solutions in [Grid system for slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192637/1952)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `remember picture, overlay` as options to a `tikzpicture` you can then use `current page` as a coordinate (well actually you use `.north` or stuff like that, just like you can use `node.north` as the top of a node named `node`).

The `remember picture` has the effect that the positioning of the picture is adapted to match the specified positions because the `tikzpicture` is not guaranteed to be at the bottom left of the current page -- you use it somewhere in the `frame` environment and it is there as far as LaTeX is concerned. Ti*k*Z stores that position in the .aux file and moves the picture accordingly on the second run. Therefore you need at least two runs with this approach to get correct positioning. `overlay` just makes sure that your picture doesn't have a size as far as LaTeX's typesetting is concerned (it still introduces white space around the spot it is used in if used at the wrong place -- make sure to not start a new paragraph accidentally and put a `%` after `\end{tikzpicture}` to not introduce unwanted spaces).

---

If you want to place arbitrary stuff on a specified coordinate on a frame, I'd use a `\node` in a `tikzpicture` which I know is on that slide. For a small template I created for myself I used the following approach:

1. Put a `tikzpicture` in the beamer template `background`. In that `tikzpicture` put a macro like `\MyPlacedStuff` and after the `tikzpicture` put `\gdef\MyPlacedStuff{}`.
2. In a `frame` you can now add stuff with `\xdef\MyPlacedStuff{\unexpanded\expandafter{\MyPlacedStuff <stuff you want to place on the slide>}}`

You should write a macro or two around point 2 to ease the process.

The following does that and adds the help lines if you use `\HelpLinestrue` outside of the frame (until you use `\HelpLinesfalse`).

`\PlaceAt` takes the coordinates in multiples of `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` as first argument in `()`, optional arguments to a `\node` in `[]`, and finally the contents of the node in `{}`. The first and last are mandatory, options to the node are optional.

`\AddToPlaced` takes only one argument, which should be able to contain anything you can add to a `tikzpicture`.

**Beware** the `background` might already contain stuff which you hereby would overwrite. You'll have to sort that out if it conflicts. It seems to not conflict in your MWE.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections,through,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\newif\ifHelpLines
\newcommand*\MyPlacedStuff{}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%>>>
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \ifHelpLines
      \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \fi
    \MyPlacedStuff
  \end{tikzpicture}\gdef\MyPlacedStuff{}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\PlaceAt}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}r() O{} +m }
  {%
    \PlaceAtB#1{#2}{#3}%
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\PlaceAtB}{ m m m +m }
  {%
    \xdef\MyPlacedStuff%
      {%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\MyPlacedStuff
          \node[#3] at (#1\paperwidth,#2\paperheight) {#4};%
        }%
      }%
  }
\newcommand{\AddToPlaced}[1]
  {%
    \xdef\MyPlacedStuff%
      {%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\MyPlacedStuff#1}%
      }%
  }

\begin{document}
\HelpLinestrue
\begin{frame}{Slide}
  \PlaceAt(.8,.6){This text}
  \AddToPlaced{\draw (.1,1) -- (.9\textwidth,.9\textheight);}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. It accomplishes the goal of the MWE, but perhaps Im not being clear. My basic question is this: How does positioning work in a beamer slide, and a tikz image? I guess a long answer to that is the beamer doc and the tikz docs. Is there a shorter answer around?

Comment: @user79950 In `beamer` you get your frame filled from top to bottom with stretches inserted depending on your positioning (vertically centred, top aligned, ...). The frame's title and subtitle are added at first, then the body, then the foot. There might be some other elements, but those are the main parts. In Ti*k*Z you put stuff at positions inside the `tikzpicture` using coordinates. The `tikzpicture` has its own coordinate system. It is converted to a single object with a bounding box for TeX's typesetting. To mix the two worlds (`beamer` and Ti*k*Z), you can use something like the above.

Comment: @user79950 to be clearer: `beamer` doesn't use Ti*k*Z coordinates for positioning but a positioning based on TeX's typesetting algorithms. There simply is no "absolute grid" in `beamer` by default.

Comment: Is there a way to have all "boxes" draw their borders and names with a grid? That way I can at least see whats on teh page and with what coordiante system? Im coming over from powerpoint, and have only used tex for documents so I never really had to worry about spacing.

Comment: @user79950 You asked a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427075/121799), right? I think that you may benefit from trusting TeX to do the positioning for you. Personally I almost never use absolute placement but only relative. I can see that in the very beginning it is a bit hard to anticipate where certain elements will be placed, but trust me that after a relatively short time you'll have figured that out. I regard it as a big advantage of LaTeX that it takes care of the positioning and lets me focus on the relevant things.

Comment: @user79950 all those `beamer` elements aren't aligned to any coordinate system. It is just TeX's typesetting fitted into a slide. There is no real coordinate system in `beamer`. Just a page and a measurement how much of it is filled. Every `frame` environment inserts those common elements (headline, frame title, body, footline, etc.) and stacks those over each other. The closest you can get to what you want is either a `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]` or the above approach.

Comment: @Skillmon how do I make sure tikz gets two runs when Im using a tool like lyx?

Comment: @user79950 sorry, but LyX is beyond the scope of my expertise. Does LyX get cross referencing right on first run? If so that most likely means that it does run more than once internally. What you posted below (in your answer) can easily be achieved with my static `tikzpicture` in the `background` approach, too.

Answer (score 3):

For what its worth, this is a simple example of something I was trying to achieve.

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
        \node at (current page.north west) [fill=red!20,rounded
    corners,below right] {Top Left}; 
    \node at (current page.south west) [fill=red!20,rounded
    corners,above right] {Bottom Left}; 
    \node at (current page.south east) [fill=red!20,rounded
    corners,above left] {Bottom Right}; 
    \node at (current page.north east) [fill=red!20,rounded
    corners,below left] {Top Right}; 
    \node at (current page) [fill=red!20,rounded
    corners] {Center}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```