# How to align eso-pic & tikz coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, eso-pic

I have a grid on my beamer slides generated by:

```
\usepackage[texcoord,grid,gridunit=mm,gridcolor=black!30,subgridcolor=gray!10]{eso-pic}
```

I'd like to draw a rectangle in `tikz` with:

```
\draw [textpos,color=yellow,fill=yellow!25] (0,0) -- (10,0) rectangle (20,10) -- (30,10);
```

How can I align `tikz` with `eso-pic`?

Comment: Why do you need `eso-pic` to draw a grid? beamer has a build in grid option: `\setbeamertemplate{background}[grid]`

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Which libraries are necessary for the `textpos` key?

Comment: Unless you are using absolute positioning of your tikz image, you will have to repeat the alignment for every single slide.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427691/positioning-and-coordinates-in-tikzbeamer

Comment: You can also draw the background grid with Ti*k*Z. If you use `\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]` then you can merge in arbitrary additional `tikzpicture`s later. (I am not saying that the `eso-pic` grid won't work, however using Ti*k*Z for all of these makes things simpler.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is straightforward to synchronize the coordinate systems of `eso-pic` with an overlay `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[texcoord,grid,gridunit=mm,gridcolor=black!30,subgridcolor=gray!10]{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A slide}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,x=1mm,y=-1mm,shift={(current
page.north west)}]
\draw[-latex] (40,40) -- (60,60);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you are willing to append `remember picture` to every Ti*k*Z picture you can literally use your suggested notation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[texcoord,grid,gridunit=mm,gridcolor=black!30,subgridcolor=gray!10]{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{textpos/.style={overlay,x=1mm,y=-1mm,shift={(current page.north
west)}},every picture/.append style={remember picture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A slide}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[textpos,-latex] (40,40) -- (60,60);
\draw [textpos,color=yellow,fill=yellow!25] (0,0) -- (10,0) rectangle (20,10) -- (30,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]