# How to set up greek math fonts fonts for Minion Pro in LuaLaTex

Tags: fonts, luatex

In `XeLaTex` and using `mathspec`, one can simply use text Greek letters of Minion Pro for math symbols:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Greek,Latin)[Numbers={Proportional}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro}

\begin{document} 
    Here is an equation.
    \begin{equation*}
    |\psi_{u,v}|^2 = 1
    \end{equation*}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to achieve the same in `LuaLaTex` using `unicode-math` and `mathastext`. Following the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238209/general-guide-on-how-to-set-up-minion-pro-for-math-in-lualatex), I ended up with

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{MinionPro}

\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-It}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-BoldIt}
\setmathrm{MinionPro}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\begin{document} 
    Here is an equation.
    \begin{equation*}
|\psi_{u,v}|^2 = 1
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

that yields the error  below:

```
Package unicode-math Error: No main maths font has been set up yet. \setmathfont
```

But I have already set a math font. What is a work-around here?

Comment: as the mathastext documentation writes "Particularly in the latter case (i.e. using unicode-math) you probably don’t need, don’t want, and should not use mathastext". So don't do it. Use only unicode-math, and set up as base font a real math font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I don't have the real base math of my desired font.

Comment: well then you will have to choose some other math font. E.g. \setmathfont{Cambria Math} or whatever. unicode-math requires a math font, you can't fake that by combining letters from various text fonts.

Comment: @User so you do, that's odd (I deleted the comment) I can' believe mathspec really needs xetex,I wonder why it has that test)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it relies on `\XeTeXglyphbounds` (I looked in the code).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes was just looking. you and Marcel could fix that  in luaotfload? :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522751/2388. Probably mathspec only needs to adopt that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I was under the impression that `LuaLaTeX` (and related packages working with it) can do anything `XeLaTeX` (and its related packages) can do, including such font-faking tricks.

Comment: oh https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522751/1090 I was going to say same:-)

Comment: @User that lualatex can theoretically do something doesn't imply that a package implements it. Make a feature request for mathspec ...