# Why does LuaLaTeX not accept this date format in the PDF file?

Tags: luatex, pdf, date

Here's a complete MWE to modify a PDF file and include it in `lualatex`, which fails:

```
wget https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf -O dummy.pdf
grep -a Date dummy.pdf
sed -E "s-/CreationDate\(D:.*\)-/CreationDate(D:19700101000000)-" -i dummy.pdf
grep -a Date dummy.pdf
echo "\documentclass{article}\usepackage{graphicx}\begin{document}\includegraphics{dummy.pdf}\end{document}" | lualatex
```

The document in question is very simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{dummy.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
! error:  (file dummy.pdf) (pdf inclusion): reading image failed
```

It seems that `lualatex` does not like the truncated PDF date - this variant works fine:

```
wget https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf -O dummy.pdf
grep -a Date dummy.pdf
sed -E "s-/CreationDate\(D:.*\)-/CreationDate(D:19700101000000+01'00')-" -i dummy.pdf
grep -a Date dummy.pdf
echo "\documentclass{article}\usepackage{graphicx}\begin{document}\includegraphics{dummy.pdf}\end{document}" | lualatex
```

But I believe that `lualatex` is too picky here, as the date of the modified PDF file is valid. Compare https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/pdf-explained/9781449321581/ch04.html

> All parts of the date after the year are optional. For example, `(D:1999)` is perfectly valid.

Comment: If you change the length of the entry you are breaking the byte count and so the pdf.

Comment: ... also the xref table

Comment: this is not really related to luatex, you have made the pdf file invalid

Comment: Thanks, all of you are right! I did not notice as Acrobat Reader (and several other viewers) display the file just fine. I have fixed my script to replace only as many characters as there are in the original file to maintain the byte count, and `lualatex` is accepted the files now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was not related to LaTeX and it was solved in comments.