# How do I make a framed coffin with correct alignment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, framed, minipage, xcoffins

I'm playing with coffins for a title page and would like to have a square framed box that aligns with the topline and baseline of text within a rotated coffin.  I have a couple of issues with this so far that I need some help with:

1. There appears to be a margin to the left and right of the frame that produces space between the handles and the frame.  Why is this here and how can I fix it?
2. The framed box, in addition to not being square, is too large.  How can I set the size of the framed box to match the height of the text?

[image]

From the image (edited a bit to show the problem) the handles on the text appear to be where I would expect as are the handles on the top and bottom of the framed box.  MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
    \NewCoffin \result
    \NewCoffin \TRBlock
    \NewCoffin \LeftMar

    \SetHorizontalCoffin \result {}


    \SetHorizontalCoffin \LeftMar {\fontsize{52}{50}\selectfont\color{gray}D}
    \SetHorizontalCoffin \TRBlock {
        \fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][\CoffinHeight\LeftMar]{\CoffinHeight\LeftMar}\centering A\end{minipage}}
    }

    \RotateCoffin \LeftMar {90}
    \JoinCoffins\result[vc,hc]\LeftMar[r,vc]
    \JoinCoffins\result[\LeftMar-B,\LeftMar-r] \TRBlock[r,b]
    \TypesetCoffin \result
\end{document}
```

Comment: As standard, `\fbox` adds a margin: try setting `\fboxsep = 0 pt `. Also, watch for additional spaces: you need a `%` after the `{` in the `\SetHorizontalCoffin \TRBlock` line, for example.

Comment: If you're thinking of doing additional precision-fitting of ink into coffins, [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34563/precision-copyfitting-in-xcoffin) may also be helpful.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks Joseph, that did the trick.  I should have thought of the space, but didn't know about the fboxsep.  Would you  mind posting that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Something of a comment made into an answer.]

As standard, `\fbox` adds a margin: try setting `\fboxsep = 0 pt`. Also, watch for additional spaces: you need a `%` after the `{` in the `\SetHorizontalCoffin \TRBlock` line, for example:

```
\SetHorizontalCoffin \TRBlock {%
    \fboxsep = 0 pt %
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][\CoffinHeight\LeftMar]{\CoffinHeight\LeftMar}\centering A\end{minipage}}
}
```