# The perfect pdfcrop

Tags: crop, standalone, bounding-box, pdfcrop

I need a "perfect" pdfcrop, one that crops **exactly** to the edge of the figure or text for alignment issues as a graphic in other programs. I'm aware of the  [`standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone), and have gone through all the questions on `pdfcrop` including the `--hires` option. Neither solution crops to *exactly* to the edge. For example, using `standalone`:

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Hi
\end{document}
```

[image]

and using `pdfcrop --hires`:

[image]

As you can see, `pdfcrop` is close, but I need something exact. I think that `standalone` only knows the width given by the glyphs and `pdfcrop` gets its information from `gs`. Is it possible to achieve a perfect crop using LaTeX or any external tool?

Comment: A better test example is `Ag\"e` as you will also see the most top and bottom parts.

Comment: I don't have this software, but the crop feature in **Adobe Acrobat** (Standard or Pro) might be worth trying. If I remember correctly, there is a feature in the crop tool to remove surrounding white space.

Comment: @JohnReed: The feature is there but has similar “problems” like the other mentioned tools. So better trying before buying ;-)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275374/what-is-the-local-height-of-a-capital-letter/275381#275381

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To be able to crop a vector graphic reliably you must "print" it to see where the black dots are.

"Printing" always involves a resolution: the black dots must have a positive size.

pdfcrop uses the bbox device of ghostscript. According to the documentation of ghostscript the default resolution of this device is 4000 dpi.

You can change this resolution but simply enlarging it doesn't mean that you get a more "perfect" result: To be able to decide if a crop is "perfect" you must "print" it e.g. to a screen to see where the black dots are and on the lower resolution of the screen you will  see your "exact" crop only at a very large zoom.

Comment: 1] Is there a way to get a higher resolution than the setting of `--hires` (which I'm assuming is the 4000 dpi you are talking about)? 2] If a vector graphic is simply a collection of (bézier?) curves, isn't it possible to mathematically determine the bounding box _without_ printing?

Comment: 1. Theoretically yes. I can e.g. do something like this: `C:\Test>mgs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=bbox -r8000 -g800000x800000 test-utf8.pdf` (`mgs` is the ghostscript in miktex). 2. I have no idea how difficult if would be to calculate a perfect resolution independant bounding box: But as the dots on your screen have a size they will no be able to stop exactly at this bounding box. You can't avoid the resolution issue. (And naturally the values don't need to be rational numbers).

Comment: Link to [gs documentation about bbox](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/AFPL/8.00/Devices.htm#Test)

Answer (score 9):

To expand on Ulrike's excellent answer:

The reason this is only guaranteed after rendering the font to an actual pixel map is that there is, in principle, no obligatory relation between a glyph's *ink* and its *bounding box*.

Here's an example; a lower-case 'm' from URW Nimbus Sans:

[image: font view of a glyph m]

The left and right sidebearings (the space between the ink and the bounding box) are shown. TeX , of course, sets to the bounding box, and not the ink 'for typographical reasons'.

If precision copyfitting *before* the final pixel map rendering is important for you, a solution which allows you to access the sidebearing values is available with XeTeX, as described [in this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34563/precision-copyfitting-in-xcoffin) However, this is not guaranteed 100%.

Comment: Thank you very much for that link! I think it may be the solution I'm looking for. I'm also trying to learn the proper typographic vernacular, is _ink_ the proper term here?

Comment: @Hooked: Don't know; I just pulled it out of the top of my head as being (probably) a clear name for what I was talking about...

Answer (score 2):

*Expanding the comment of @ulrike-fischer, as it contains the solution that works in most of the cases I deal with - and as I guess this might help in many similar situations:*

If your goal is to have no margins, and if `pdfcrop` crops/clips/moves parts of the content beyond the image borders, or if there remain some margins, then a combination of higher resolution (`--hires`) *and* larger image scaling (`--resolution WIDTHxHEIGHT`) might be a quick and practical solution:

`pdfcrop --hires --resolution 1000x1000 my.pdf`

If it needs to be more exact, then increase the resolution further:

`pdfcrop --hires --resolution 50000x50000 my.pdf`

In most cases I deal with this solves the problem in a quick and practical way, though there might be special cases where this is not exact enough.